# Calling a function inside a function gets me a undefined "this" in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to call a function that changes something in "this" from inside a navigator render function.

So my render() function looks like this:

```
render() {
return(
  <Navigator
    ref='Navigator'
    initialRoute={{name: 'timetable'}}
    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
  />
);
}
```

This is my renderScene function:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
if(route.name === 'timetable') {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Content>
    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      ref='ScrollView'
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      onScroll={this._onScroll.bind(this)}
    >
    <View style={{width: this.state.width}}>
    <Timetable day='Ponedeljek' date='6.3.2017' />
    </View>
    <View style={{width: this.state.width}}>
    <Timetable day='Torek' date='7.3.2017' />
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
    <PageControlIOS
      currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
      numberOfPages={2}
      pageIndicatorTintColor="grey"
      currentPageIndicatorTintColor="#ff3b30"
      style={{margin: -10}}
      onValueChange={this._onPageControlValueChange.bind(this)}
    />
    </Content>
    </View>
  )
}else if (route.name === 'allSubstitutions') {
  return (
    <AllSubstitutions navigator={navigator}/>
  )
}
}
```

And the problem happens when the onValueChange function from  gets called which looks like this:

```
_onPageControlValueChange(currentPage) {
this.refs.ScrollView.scrollResponderScrollTo({x: this.state.width * currentPage, y: 0, animated: true})
  }
```

The error I get is "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.refs.ScrollView.scrollResponderScrollTo').

If i just replace the inside of the render() function with the content of the renderScene() it works as intended.

If you have any idea whats happening i would love to hear the solution, thanks.

Comment: Try binding the event handler in the constructor of the component, i.e. `this._onPageControlValueChange = this._onPageControlValueChange.bind(this)`

Comment: The error isn't telling you that `this` is undefined; it's telling you `this.refs.ScrollView` is undefined. (If `this` was undefined the error would say "evaluating `this.refs`").

Comment: @colti does not help at all, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems like this is a problem with the way you defined your `ref` on the `ScrollView` component.  Try doing something like this instead:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={(scrollView) => { this.scrollView = scrollView; }}
```

and then

```
_onPageControlValueChange(currentPage) {
    this.scrollView.scrollResponderScrollTo({x: this.state.width * currentPage, y: 0, animated: true})
  }
```

Comment: You might want to change `{ this.scrollView = input; }` for `{ this.scrollView = scrollView; }`. But it is  good answer